# merge two regex

Tags: regex, scala

i want to merge two regex.I am using '|' operator but it is not working.

Regex1

```
"[!#&%()$-@&*0-9]"
```

Regex2

```
"\\S*\\S\\1\\1\\S*\\s?"
```

I want to remove special characters from the string and remove words which contain more than three repetitive characters

Comment: how it is not working?

Comment: my input is str = " abcc ag4%$ bgggg sffsfss" and the output is empty string  for every input i want the output to be = "abcc ag"

Comment: your first regex is incorrect and also second

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to remove special characters from the string and remove words which contain more than three repetitive characters

Comment: maybe you should edit the question and add this information - it's quite misleading without it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex(considering `_` and space is not special)

```
[^\w ]|([\w])\1{3}
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI6vV7/2)**

If you want to remove the entire word you can use

```
[^\w ]|\S*([\w])\1{3}\S*
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hI6vV7/4)**

Comment: @RahulAgrawal you can accept the answer if it helped